# How save a C++ pointer in python to pass it again later?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm trying to create something and I don't know if it's possible or "clean" :

1. From python, call function A of my C++ code to compute something complicated
2. The C++ code returns just the pointer to the python
3. Do other things in python...
4. From python, call function B of my C++ code, it takes the pointer and other things as arguments.

I really don't need to use my complicated C++ class in my Python algorithm, that's why I just want to save the pointer in python.

Anyone has any advice on how to do that ?

Edit : In the end I wrapped the c++ class in python, thank you everyone.

Comment: The "pointer" should only be an opaque handler, python-side?

Comment: For that pointer thingie to make sense, the C++ code must retain the associated data anyway. It is any use for the Python code to know where this data resides ? Maybe you are not telling us the whole story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is just data that can be marshaled and sent to anything. It is however a very bad idea because when doing that, you have to assure that that pointer remains valid as long as the python part has the pointer. There is no possibility to check whether the pointer is still valid, so dereferencing a pointer that you receive from an external party could crash your program.

A better idea in a lot of situations is to send a key to a table. When that key is sent back, it can be used to get the needed information from that table and it can be handled when the table doesn't have the key anymore. It is easiest to use `std::map` for the table. Of course, you could store the pointer in a container and check for that, but a string or number is easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose that's why I'm getting seg faults when returning a void*.
If I understand correctly this idea of table, there is a map on the C++ side and I can return the index of my specific object to python. But how do I make the map persistant in my C++ functions ?

Comment: I was thinking of making a class in C++, but then you probably don't even need the pointer or key anyway: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html but you can always use file scoped global variables if all else fails. Mind you, I haven't worked with cython yet, we tended to communicate between C++ and python via some protocol, so my answer could be less useful.

Comment: "send a key to a table": what does that mean ? Who holds the table ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create a class in C++ and store that pointer in the class itself as private. Then create function calls to access those pointers.

Once the class is implemented generate the .so file of your lib and import it in python. This way you can simply use your C++ code in python and also will not have to save the pointer.